# Insert dicionary inside a pyspark df column

Tags: python, pyspark

i have a dictionary and i want to put it inside a column, how can i achieve it?

```
{' Bariatrics': 13, ' Cardiovascular / Pulmonary': 347, ' Neurology': 198...}
```

Goal:

```
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|   medical_specialty|medical specialty                                     |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|                male|{' Bariatrics': 13, ' Cardiovascular / Pulmonary': 347|
|              female|{' Bariatrics': 7, ' Cardiovascular / Pulmonary':  127|
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

this is the code i have

```
m=[gender0["medical_specialty"] for gender0 in gender0.rdd.collect()]
dictmale={a:m.count(a) for a in m}
```

-

```
c= spark.createDataFrame(
  [
    ('Male', dictmale),
    ("Female",dictfemale),

  ],
  ['Gender',"medical_specialty"]
)
display(c)
```

but it gives me error:

```
TypeError: field medical_specialty: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.MapType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.ArrayType'>
```

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi, `TypeError: element in array field medical_specialty: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.MapType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'>`

Comment: both entries of `medical_speciality` need to be of same type. u need to ensure `dictmale` and `dictfemale` are both same type

Comment: according to your error(in the question), it seemed that dictfemale was of `arraytype` and dictmale was of `maptype`, so I suggested to to use `[dictmale]`. in spark all rows in a column need to be of the same datatype.

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi, thank you man, it solved, i was not aware that dictmale and dictfemale are different types.